# Unable to get an alert after the API response

Tags: api, cypress, alert, fixtures

I'm trying to get the alert to assert the text, but the problem is that when the cy.get(.alert) command is executing the alert is not visible anymore for some reason, even tho it's displayed on the page for several seconds, and after the cy.get(.alert)

**The runner:**
At cy.wait
[image]
At cy.get('.alert')
[image]
After cy.get('.alert')
[image]
HTML
[image]

**My code:**

```js
   cy.intercept('POST', Cypress.env('backdev3URL')+'/bap/one_sst_bap/create').as('createResponse')
    cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/BAPdata.json').then(BAPdata => {
        cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/PurchaseData.json').then(PurchaseData => {
            
            cy.wait('@tableRequest')
           
            cy.get('#subcontractors_datatable tbody').find('tr td:nth-child(1)').each((row,index) => {
                if(row.text().includes("ABJ MENUISERIE")){
                    cy.get('#subcontractors_datatable tbody tr').eq(index).find('td:nth-child(2)').then(Nb => {
                        BAPdata.BAPnumber = Nb.text()
                        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/BAPdata.json', BAPdata)
                    })
                    cy.get('#subcontractors_datatable tbody tr').eq(index).contains('button', 'BAP').click()   
                }
            })
            cy.wait('@createResponse').then(() => {
                cy.get('.alert').should('contain',
                'Le BAP N°'+PurchaseData.BDCid+year+month+day+' pour le sous traitant avec ID '+PurchaseData.BDCid+' a été créé avec succés')
            })
          
            var date = PurchaseData.BDCdate.split(' ')[0].replace(/\//g, ' ')
            var day = date.split(' ')[0]+'1'
            var month = date.split(' ')[1]
            var year = date.split(' ')[2].replace(/20/, '')
            const creationDate = require('dayjs')

            BAPdata.BAPid = Number(BAPdata.lastBAPid)+Number(1)  
            BAPdata.SstBAPnumber = PurchaseData.SSTid+year+month+day
            BAPdata.BAPdate = creationDate().format('DD/MM/YYYY')

            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/BAPdata.json', BAPdata)


        })
    })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the HTML code where the `.alert` element is?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is failing because there are differences in the data displayed in the alert

- `PurchaseData.BDCid` is `642705` in the fixture but `20577` in the alert
- `PurchaseData.BDCid+year+month+day` has some undefined values

You could probably just check part of the string to ensure the alert occurs and is the right one.

```js
cy.get('.alert')
  .should('contain', 'pour le sous traitant avec ID')  // enough to identify
```

But if you want to test with the actual data, you should intercept and stub the POST request with the same values in the fixture `PurchaseData.json`.

Also get rid of `cy.wait(1000)` before `cy.get('.alert')`.

Comment: Don't mind the text, I know it's wrong, the problem is that the element .alert is not found.
See the first screenshot "Expected to find element .alert, but never found it".

I cannot manage to get that .alert element! 
I tried with intercepting the API then wait for it and get the element, and without waiting for API, but as soon as cypress looks for .alert, it's dissapearing from the DOM.
And I added the cy.wait(1000) because after clicking the element takes a few miliseconds to be displayed.

Comment: After clicking in the BAP button, the alert is displayed for 4-5 seconds before fading out.

Comment: The alert is displayed right after cypress intercepts @createReponse, watch the HTML screenshot. I updated the code.

Comment: The thing is, if you just do `cy.get('.alert')` without the contains part (as an experiment) are you catching it? And `cy.wait(1000)` isn't needed because `cy.get('.alert')` already has 4000ms wait/retry built in - and you can add more timeout if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I'm catching the cy.get('.alert'), you were right, the issue was in the assertion text, I was confused by the "Expected to find element .alert" but never found it."